# Unique function doesn't work in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

(http://angularjs/angular.min.js:109:313)  ngRepeat: mapImg in imgCat | unique:'select'

unique function doesn't work in server. but function work in localhost

Comment: Since it works for localhost, could you show us how you include 'angular-filter.min.js'? Do you use an actual copy of the file or a link to an online resource?

Comment: bottom of the file. using link

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS doesn't come with a unique filter by default. I hope you're using one of the custom filters in your app. If not you can use the one from angular-filter. Include the javascript and inject in your application dependency.
[angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Please share your code in plunker if you still need assistance.